# How Name Node decides which are the different data blocks stored in a data node, when it gets down?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Let's suppose some data node gets down, then it will stop sending heartbeats. Now, name node has come to know that this particular data node is no more in the network. Name node again has to create blocks for maintaining the replication factor. How name node come to know that what are all the different copies of a block are there on the dead data node. If it will start iterating over the FSImage then definitely it will be a very long process, and will take long. So, what is the exact procedure followed by the name node to know what are the different data blocks stored on the dead data node?

Answer (score 0):

The blockmap is maintained in memory so all the blocks that reside on the failed host can be found pretty quickly.

It is a function of the size map though, no more than 4gb.

Answer (score 0):

NameNode periodically receives a Heartbeat and a Block report from each of the DataNodes in the cluster. Receipt of a Heartbeat implies that the DataNode is healthy and functioning properly.

A Blockreport contains a list of all blocks on a DataNode. When NameNode notices that it has not received a heartbeat message from a data node after a certain amount of time, the data node is marked as dead. Since blocks will be under-replicated the system begins replicating the blocks that were stored on the dead DataNode.

The easiest way of understanding this scenario is when a Data node is down and there is no way other data nodes can know what neighboring data node had stored. The Blocks are replicated in the data nodes as per the Namenode instructions which in turn checks the blocks of dead data node from its fsimage and this will take less than 5 seconds to decide what to be replicated. Once decided replication will take a couple of minutes to complete.

Answer (score -1):

DataNode sends block report for every fixed amount of time(by default set to 21600000 milliseconds).
Block report contains Information about the blocks, which contains: block ID, block length, block generation timestamp, state of the block replica (For e.g. replica is finalized or waiting to be recovered etc.)